# Question about Ersatzinfinitiv/modal verb

Tags: modal-verb

He saw it coming - Er hat es kommen sehen. I understand it's not 'gesehen' because sehen is treated like a modal verb. However, if I were to say "he must have seen it coming" by adding 'er muss', it becomes "Er muss es kommen gesehen haben", instead of just kommen sehen haben. Why does the 'sehen' gain a 'ge-' in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With "sehen", the *Ersatzinfinitiv* is optional. Your first sentence could simply look like

> Er hat es kommen gesehen.

Which would be just about as correct and idiomatic as your example. "sehen" doesn't necessarily have to be considered a modal verb here.

Your second example, without the "kommen" looks like

> Er muss es gesehen haben

(Remember *Ersatzinfinitiv* is optional with sehen)

Actually,

> er muss es kommen sehen haben

is just as correct and idiomatic as your example

> er muss es kommen gesehen haben

lots of infinitives in a row, however is a complex thing that most native speakers' "Sprachgefühl" wants to avoid, so it remembers "ah, this was optional" and evades it.

Let's use an example where the *Ersatzinfinitiv* is not optional (because we're using a "true" modal verb). Assume you want to say

> We will have had to accept our fate [Futur II]

this translates to

> wir werden unser Schicksal haben hinnehmen müssen

No way to avoid the four infinitives in one sentence here.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation! No grammar rules seem to have been broken then (no new exceptions to learn yay)

Comment: Note that the construction "Er hat es kommen sehen müssen" is also possible, though with different meaning

Comment: Werden is not an infinitive here, but 3rd person plural of werden. It does look like the infinitive though.

Comment: @infinitezero Right. But well, I'll add another one, if you like ;) Insert between "hinnehmen" and "müssen": *können*

Comment: @tofro we had another question about that, somewhere on this site :D

Comment: It's ironic that *hin-* (in hinnehmen) and *ge-* (hypothetically in some constructs) could come from the same source, eventually? The ge-prefix is assigned to PIE \*Kom- (as in Latin *co-*, \*K is palatalized, usually spelled with a diacrit) after Verner's law, but *here, hin*, as well as Dutch *het* ("conj. "that", etc.), Engl. *it*, Lat. et-*ce*-tera, *(hi)c* ("here"), Ita. *-ci* (ca. "they, there") are from \*Ke-, Grimm's law. The development of the prefix (s.a. *enough* ~ *genug*, Low German *ge-, e-, je-*, thus \* *ha[v] ic'[e]sehn*?) is uncertain. Is this *ge-* a relative pronoun clitic?