# Jmdn. sterben gesehen zu haben & vor den Augen jmds

Tags: genitive, past-participle

> Julius Jones war 19, als er in Verdacht geriet, einen 45 Jahre alten Geschäftsmann erschossen zu haben, vor den Augen seine Kinder, nur, um dessen Auto zu stehlen.

> Tochter Rachel Howell hat vor über 20 Jahren ihren Vater sterben sehen und bittet den Gouverneur, das Urteil zu vollstrecken.

I think I see mistakes with these two sentences. It should have been vor den Augen seine**R** Kinder & sterben **GE**sehen (capital letters for emphasis). Would you agree? They're from this: https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/amerika/oklahoma-todesstrafe-101.html

Comment: Vor den Augen der Kinder des Geschäftsmanns, nicht vor den Augen der Kinder des Täters, nehme ich an? Der Satz ist auch in dieser Hinsicht misslungen. Mit "einen 45 Jahre alten Geschäftsmann vor den Augen seiner Kinder erschossen zu haben" hätte man m.E. formulieren sollen, denn so wie es "dessen Auto" war, um das es ging, müsste man auch von "dessen Kinder" sprechen.

Answer (score 7):

You are right on first issue: genitive has to read *seiner* Kinder.

You are wrong on the second issue, however; the construct is called *Ersatzinfinitiv* and we have already some questions covering that, e. g. [Question about Ersatzinfinitiv/modal verb](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/61292).

Comment: Thank you, I'll investigate this concept.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on the Ersatzinfinitiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv) may be useful here.