# Triple "en" verb ending in a conditional with a modal verb

Tags: subjunctive, modal-verb

Is the following conditional that combines *falls* + *sollten* with a modal verb,  possible?

> Falls Sie keinen Brief von meinem Anwalt erhalten wollen sollten, ...

It sounds wrong and I'm not sure that putting *sollten* as the first verb in the sentence would help, though it does sound slightly better.

Are similar constructions (with modal verbs in them) present, and if so, how often would they occur?

Comment: *Sollten* is not an infinitive and can be be dropped without change of meaning.

Comment: @guidot thank you, I have changed the title to reflect this. Does the sentence not strike you as weird-sounding?

Comment: Yes it sounds clumsy, but not really wrong. Dropping *falls* and moving *sollten* to its place seems perfectly acceptable, however.

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/61292/1696).

Comment: You can make it even more weird by adding even more modal verbs, if you want. It will still be corrrect **grammar**. If you're asking about **style**, however, you've already overdone it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is quite bad from the perspective of euphony, but quite correct from a grammatical perspective.

Grammar is fundamentally reductive: whatever emerges from the repeated application of a finite number of constructions is considered "right", even if that result is unforeseen. Euphony works in a holistic way: it considers the totality of the result as it is, and if the result contains too many repeated elements it is judged to be infelicitous, *particularly* if the repeated surface forms are in fact different underlying mechanisms (such as "-en" being used both as an infinitive suffix and as an inflection suffix).

Comment: Thank you for the answer - and thanks to all the contributors in the comments as well. I even learned two new words from your explanation ;)

Comment: I think the combination of both *falls* and *sollten* is also questionable. It's a doubling as either of both says there are alternatives.